# Failed to build qt5.2.1 static with MSVC 2010 x86

Tags: qt, windows-7, static-libraries, qt5, visual-studio-2010

I've got Win 7 x64 and i am trying to build static qt5.2.1 from source winth MSVC 2010 x86.
The problem is

```
Generating Code...
        link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "
/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' versio
n='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture
='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:release\musicplayer.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:releas
e\musicplayer.exe @C:\Users\AuST\AppData\Local\Temp\nm7949.tmp
   Creating library release\musicplayer.lib and object release\musicplayer.exp
        mt.exe /nologo /manifest release\musicplayer.exe.embed.manifest /outputr
esource:release\musicplayer.exe;1
        cd quickplayer\ && ( if not exist Makefile E:\Lib\qt521static\qtbase\bin
\qmake E:\Lib\qt521static\qtwinextras\examples\winextras\quickplayer\quickplayer
.pro -o Makefile ) && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BI
N\nmake.exe" -f Makefile
Project ERROR: Plugin qml_winextras is missing a classname entry, please add one
 to the qmldir file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x3'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Don't compile the examples :)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone runs into the same issue, not compiling the examples will not work, although it seems an obvious solution. After comparing .qmake.conf in qtwinextras and in another module's directory, I added the following lines to the .qmake.conf (seems like there is a bug with configure for this module):

```
CONFIG += qt_example_installs
CONFIG += warning_clean
```

After that, compilation went on fine--of course without examples.